# dpkg-scanpackages -a amd64 . > Packages - Wrote 0 entries with --arch arm64

Tags: apt

I am trying to pack(and create a repo on github) using the following, but dpkg-scanpackages is not writing anything when using --arch arm64?

control file:

```
Package: hello-world
Version: 0.0.1
Maintainer: example <example@example.com>
Depends: git
Architecture: arm64
Homepage: http://example.com
Description: A program that prints hello
```

Created .deb file and verified with `dpkg-deb --contents ./arm64`

```
dpkg-deb -b ./arm64
```

Wrote 1 entries:

```
dpkg-scanpackages --multiversion . > Packages
dpkg-scanpackages: info: Wrote 1 entries to output Packages file.
```

### Problem

Wrote 0 entries with --arch arm64:

```
dpkg-scanpackages --arch amd64 . > Packages
dpkg-scanpackages: info: Wrote 0 entries to output Packages file.
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I think maybe the deb package name should contain the arch app_0.0.1_arm64.deb. I found it to be working on arm64, but I have not testet it on other arch distributions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solution form Chris G. works for me: make sure that name of your .deb file contains the architecture like this:

```
XnViewMP-linux-64_amd64.deb
```

After this, dpkg-scanpackages work me as expected:

```
gabor@focal-autoinstall:/var/www/html/repo$ ll pool/main/
total 53664
drwxrwxr-x 2 gabor gabor     4096 May 21 14:54 ./
drwxrwxr-x 3 gabor gabor     4096 May 21 14:46 ../
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gabor gabor 54943400 May  3 13:25 XnViewMP-linux-64_amd64.deb
gabor@focal-autoinstall:/var/www/html/repo$ dpkg-scanpackages --arch amd64 pool/
Package: xnview
Version: 1.00.0
Architecture: amd64
Maintainer: None <none@none.com>
Installed-Size: 16
Depends: libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libbz2-1.0, libc6 (>= 2.17), libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.10.0), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libcups2 (>= 1.4.0), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libdrm2 (>= 2.4.30), libegl1-mesa | libegl1, libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11), libfreetype6 (>= 2.3.5), libgcc1 (>= 1:3.4), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libgl1-mesa-glx | libgl1, libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.33.14), libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0), libgstreamer1.0-0 (>= 1.4.0), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.5.18), libopenal1 (>= 1.14), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 0.99.1), libpulse0 (>= 0.99.4), libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9), libstdc++6 (>= 5), libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1), libx11-xcb1, libxcb-shm0, libxcb1 (>= 1.8), libxcb-xinerama0, libxext6, libxfixes3, libxi6 (>= 2:1.5.99.2), libxv1, zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.4), libopenal1
Filename: pool/main/XnViewMP-linux-64_amd64.deb
Size: 54943400
MD5sum: cf5aea700b14b50fe657c406f6f84894
SHA1: a27d7a0d17dc11825666c9175b974f51f5e7d69f
SHA256: 6f409eb6d890a827bd382b38a8a9e89eacbad6eb2b5edba01265bd20f2ed3655
Section: graphics
Priority: optional
Homepage: http://www.xnview.com
Description: Graphic viewer, browser, converter.

dpkg-scanpackages: info: Wrote 1 entries to output Packages file.
gabor@focal-autoinstall:/var/www/html/repo$
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably `foo/` is missing, so try this:

```
dpkg-scanpackages --arch arm64 pool/ > dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages
```